# Why am I getting this NoClassDefFound error?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to create a contract in Spring(https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-contract)

This is the error I keep getting:

> Tests in error: ContractVerifierTest.validate_shouldReturnPreviousAddress:19 » NoClassDefFound

And this is the line causing the problem:

```
// given:
MockMvcRequestSpecification request = given();
```

This is my groovy file:

```
package contracts

import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract


Contract.make {

    request {
        method 'GET'
        url value(consumer('/echo'), producer('/echo'))
    }
    response {
        status 200
        headers {
            header(
                    'Content-Type', value(consumer('text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1'), producer(regex('text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1')))
            )
        }
        body(
                "Send me something!"
        )
    }
    priority 1
}
```

And I have included the following in my pom file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
            <baseClassForTests>[baseClass link]</baseClassForTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As far as I can see, the line causing this problem is correct. Is there something else I could be missing?

EDIT:

On closer inspection, this seems to be the real cause of the issue:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/restassured/internal/common/assertion/AssertParameter

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError are often caused by mismatched versions of dependencies. I would make sure the version of RestAssured is compatible with spring cloud contract.

Comment: Turns out the problem was that I had some dependecies that were outdated

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

The above error usually happens due to a mismatch between Spring Cloud and Spring Boot versions.

Spring Cloud releases are tied to specific Spring Boot versions. One can refer the following useful table in the [Spring Cloud documentation](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud):

**Release train Spring Boot compatibility**

| Release Train | Boot Version |
| --- | --- |
| 2021.0.x aka Jubilee | 2.6.x, 2.7.x (Starting with 2021.0.3) |
| 2020.0.x aka Ilford | 2.4.x, 2.5.x (Starting with 2020.0.3) |
| Hoxton | 2.2.x, 2.3.x (Starting with SR5) |
| Greenwich | 2.1.x |
| Finchley | 2.0.x |
| Edgware | 1.5.x |
| Dalston | 1.5.x |

**Note:** It is recommended to use `rest-assured` that comes out of the box with Spring, to avoid any version mismatches.